# Sensitive information in Stack Trace

Tags: c#, .net, exception, stack-trace

I am wanting to discover what possible standard .net exceptions can cause stack traces to include sensitive information.

It is my understanding (correct me if I am wrong) that if a SQL connection fails then the exception message created will include the connection string which in turn might include the user name and passowrd (if not using integrated security).

We log the exception message out to log files that might be read by people that should not see that information.

What other exceptions can include information such as this that you know of?

The application in question uses Web, WCF and DB (SQL Server).

Thanks

Comment: I have never seen the connection string in the message from SQL Server. Most of the messages in a `SqlException` come straight from the server, which doesn't know about ADO.NET connection strings.

Comment: I looked into it and yes you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I don't think that you are going around this the right way.  Trying to identify the number of exceptions that could have information in them is going to expose you to risk more than likely as one item will get missed, it just happens.

I would switch focus a bit and try to identify where you can log them to be a secure location.

Another unknown to think about here is that you could have a message created by a developer that contained sensitive information, and identifying those would be very hard.

Comment: We are looking at a raft of areas of where sensitive info could be logged and one of them is creating a policy that eliminates (or tries to) developers logging this out. I just wanted to know if the .net framework internally creates stacktraces that if we were to log would contain the info.

Comment: As for secure location that is not up to us. The client doesn't want this info in the logs as they have people looking at the logs that should see any passwords etc.

Comment: The actual stack trace shouldn't give you anything that you would be concerned about.  As it will include method names only, no parameter values.  Granted that is some risk, but not a lot.